# Функция обрезки текста до определенного символа

Tags: php

```
function cut($text, $col) {
  $count = mb_strlen($text, 'UTF-8');
  $res = mb_substr($text, 0, $col, 'UTF-8');
  if ($count > $col) $res = $res . '...';
  return $res;
}
```

Нужно из этого кода сделать так, чтобы обрезал только до 3-ого слеша.

Делаю так `$col = mb_strpos($text, '/');` но он только с первого слеша режит, нужно именно только с 3-ого. Помогите, пожалуйста.

**UPD:** после 3-ого слеша

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function cut($string, $delimiter, $count) {
  $parts = explode($delimiter, $string);
  $result = implode($delimiter, array_slice($parts, 0, $count));
  return strlen($string) !== strlen($result) ? "$result/..." : $result;
}

$string = 'a/bb/ccc/dddd/eeeee';
$result = cut($string, '/', 3);
// $result: a/bb/ccc/...
```

Comment: @user246871, обновил ответ.

Comment: Благодарю Вас. :)